Formula for Arc Length of Parameterized Curve where $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is Possibly Negative
I am reading a textbook that derives the arc length formula for a parameterized curve. The derivation can be summarized by the following site.
While I understand this derivation, it is problematic to me because it assumes that $
\frac{dx}{dt}$ is non-negative across the t interval of interest, yet this is not necessarily true. In this way, I felt that my textbook (and the derivation provided) ignored important alternate cases. In the practice problems, they even applied this formula in scenarios where $\frac{dx}{dt}$ takes on negative values. This seems wrong, given that we only proved that this formula stands when $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is non-negative across the t interval of interest.
As such, I ventured to derive some of the alternate cases. For simplicity's sake, I supposed that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is negative for the interval of interest; this is not a robust case but is one instance uncovered based on the derivation provided.
While most of the derivation followed identically to the original one, one step differed. Namely, the $\frac{1}{|\frac{dx}{dt}|}$ term factored out of the radical no longer simplified to $\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ but $-\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$. This would mean that the final formula would be $-\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{(\frac{dy}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dx}{dt})^2}dt$.
Yet, this seems wrong. Moreover, it is assumed that $\alpha \leq \beta$, and we know that the integrand is certainly non-negative over any interval of t. Given this information, the formula $-\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\sqrt{(\frac{dy}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dx}{dt})^2}dt$ would yield a negative value; arc length––at least conceptually––should not be negative. Advice on where I went wrong? More importantly, how can we prove the arc-length formula in cases where $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is possibly negative over the t interval of interest?

First of all, the method of "Arc Length with Parametric Equations" in Paul's Online Notes using $\mathrm ds = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx$
assumes that $y$ is a function of $x$ over the relevant interval of the parameter $t.$
You cannot (for example) use this part of the method to measure the entire circumference of a circle, because the circle is not a curve that graphs $y$ as a function of $x.$
(The $\mathrm dy$ formula also doesn't work around an entire circle because the circle does not graph $x$ as a function of $y$.)
It doesn't make sense to let $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = f'(t)$ change sign within the interval $\alpha \leq t \leq \beta.$ If $x$ goes to the right and then to the left (or vice versa) as $t$ goes from $\alpha$ to $\beta,$ you may just have plotted a non-function like the circle.
But your objection against restricting $f'(t)$ to non-negative values is worth considering, because you can certainly trace the graph of $y$ as a function of $x$ from right to left as easily as from left to right.
The resolution to this question lies in the substitution that converts the integral over $x$ to an integral over $t.$
Revisiting the page on "Arc Length", the formula for the length of the graph of $y$ as a function of $x$ over the interval $x\in [a,b]$ is
$$
L = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx
$$
But note how this integral already has "left to right" baked into it.
You are integrating from the left end of the curve at $x=a$ to the right end at $x=b.$
This makes it simple and intuitive to make the substitution
$\mathrm dx = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt$
using $x(\alpha) = a$ and $x(\beta) = b,$ so we have
\begin{align}
L &= \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx \\
&= \int_\alpha^\beta \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}
                       \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \,\mathrm dt
\end{align}
and we continue as in Paul's Online Notes (or perhaps as in your textbook).
To trace this curve from right to left using the parameter $t$ on the interval
$\alpha \leq t \leq \beta,$ however, we need to set $x(\alpha) = b$ and $x(\beta) = a.$
So let's do the substitution $\mathrm dx = \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt$ in that case (where $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \leq 0$) like this:
\begin{align}
L &= \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx \\
&= -\int_b^a \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx \\
&= -\int_\alpha^\beta \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}
                       \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \,\mathrm dt \\
&= -\int_\alpha^\beta \frac1{\left\lvert\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right\rvert}
    \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
          + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2}
     \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \,\mathrm dt \\
&= \int_\alpha^\beta \sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
          + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dt.
\end{align}
In summary, the sign of the integral is flipped because
$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \leq 0,$
but it is flipped again because we need to convert our left-to-right integral into an equal right-to-left integral.
One sign change cancels the other.

As an aside, it makes more sense to me to develop the
$\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
          + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dt$
formula first and then derive the
$\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dx$ from it
rather than the order in which it is done in Paul's Online Notes
and in many calculus textbooks.
I think the motivation behind the textbook approach is that curves as graphs of functions are introduced much earlier than parametric curves (which a course might not even get to at all) and the authors want students to have seen an arc-length formula even if they never do parametric curves.
This may have something to do with why first-year calculus was the only math course I ever disliked on account of the subject material; it was a year of cramming techniques, and it was only during later studies in upper-level courses that I realized how it all made sense.

Among the advantages of starting with a parameterized curve and deriving the formula
$\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2
          + \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)^2} \,\mathrm dt$
directly, there is no requirement in the development of this formula that $y$ be a function of $x$ or $x$ be a function of $y.$
You can measure the entire circumference of a circle in one integral without having to do it in pieces or appeal to symmetry.
You can measure the length of a curve that loops several times.
This is all thanks to the fact that you get to integrate over $t$ using this method and $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t.$
It is only when you want to find the length of a curve using $x$ or $y$ directly as a parameter that you have to be concerned about one of the variables $x$ and $y$ being a function of the other.

Brilliant answer. It seems that I was overlooking these finer details. I always thought it was strange that answer keys for parametric integration or arc length problems often did not integrate across the entire trace (such as a circle). Rather, they would break it up into a section (such as a semi-circle) corresponding to a function of y based on x (or vice versa) and multiply based on symmetry. I now realize this break-up is necessary, since, without it, we would be trying to apply a formula that was derived on the assumption that our original curve can be rewritten as f(x) (or f(y)).

Consider the problem from here. Disregard the discussion but focus on the problem: integration on a curve that cannot be re-expressed as a function of x––one of the key assumptions for the derivation of the parametric integration and an assumption for the related arc length formula. Yet, the integration still provides the correct answer within a sign. This seems strange. Can it be shown that the condition is unnecessary by a different derivation for both formulas?

All the annoying details about left/right/up/down and x or y being a function of the other become unnecessary when you integrate with respect to t. I've added something about this in the answer. As for the area calculation, the problem is not so much left to right or right to left, it is clockwise vs. counterclockwise.
